# How to make a button stretch across the width of a column

Tags: css, html, button

I'm trying to make a button span the width of a column.

e.g. here: http://davidnhutch.com. Notice how the light grey buttons are only as large as the text they contain? I'd like each button to span the width of that column, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I've done quite a bit of looking around but am still kinda new to this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will have to make them block elements to be able to set a width:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, these buttons are so-called "inline element". The browser renderer has very complex algorithms of layouting these elements. It's like [Typesetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) but with objects on your screen instead.

CSS and HTML together influence how the algorithm works: determining the width and height, color, etc. of objects. Also their position and how text flows, or how long buttons are.

There is a limitation, however. You cannot use anything that's like a variable width for inline elements.

Adding `width: 100%; display: block` as others suggested makes some buttons perfect: but only when they start at the left or right of the containing box. If it's after a sentence, then it (should) display as:

```
<---width of container--->
Text
<----------button-------->
```

However, the button is not after "Text" anymore, but is put below it. This is because it's now a so-called "block element". It is like a full paragraph, instead of elements in a text line.

If this is what you want; fine and problem solved. If this is not what you want, and instead want:

```
<---width of container--->
Text <-------button------>
```

This is **not possible**. <sub>CCS4 would be cool if it adds `inline-width: 100%` or `inline-height`, and solve a lot of problems. However CSS4 does not exists yet.</sub>

Comment: You can always use a table ;-)

Comment: Not at all. Text generally has different size on different settings on different operating systems: the last line must be split and put in a table. However, this cannot be done deterministically to be cross-platform and cross-browser compatible: something the web *must* be these days. Hence the "not possible".

Comment: Well, I was just kidding, but using a `nowrap` on the first column, a `99%` width on the second and a `100%` width on the button might just work. But I'm not going to bother to try it out...

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width:100%` to `.button` seems to work for the center and right buttons at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That's because they have an additional class, `.right`, that floats them and converts them in block-level elements.

Comment: @jeroen - So floating an element automatically converts it to a block-level element? Is this true in all browsers? Interesting...

Comment: how would you float an inline-element? Where would you put it? And what is it's size? If you think about these questions a bit, it all makes sense.