# How to make the width of a column of bootstrap 4 buttons responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a vertical column of buttons. I have gotten it to look the way I'd like it - but when the screen is anything but lg the buttons are unresponsive. I'd like them to automatically shrink to the div they're contained in.
I've looked here: [How to make a button stretch across the width of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427186/how-to-make-a-button-stretch-across-the-width-of-a-column)
and here: [How to make buttons responsive in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955272/how-to-make-buttons-responsive-in-bootstrap)
And neither have helped. I've tried adding column sizing to the divs as well - no dice.

My code-

CSS:

```
    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #button-container {
        height: 75vh;
        width: 10%;
        margin: 5% 2.5% 0 5%;
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    #button-group {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    button {
        height: inherit;
        max-width: 100%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        display: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button-container" class="container">
<div id="button-group" class="btn-group btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg" 
role="group">
    <button id="about" type="button" class="btn">About</button>
    <button id="resume" type="button" class="btn">Resume</button>
    <button id="works" type="button" class="btn">Works</button>
    <button id="contact" type="button" class="btn">Contact</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/TravellingPumpkin/hs227bup/6/

Comment: Well you set a width of `10%`, that's not gonna work very well. Did you mean `100%`?

Comment: No, I set it to 10% because I didn't want it to span the screen - but I also needed it to be responsive - I do have a feeling that's part of my issue, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Add media queries and provide differnet width % for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, why not use the [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) for your responsive sizing? These are built in and require no custom css, just some classes. You can choose different grid sizes for different screen sizes and everything fits together nicely. The grid system is split into 12

For your example, you could remove the `width` CSS and replace it with a few grid classes.

```
<div id="button-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div id="button-group" class="btn-group btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg" role="group">
        <button id="about" type="button" class="btn">About</button>
        <button id="resume" type="button" class="btn">Resume</button>
        <button id="works" type="button" class="btn">Works</button>
        <button id="contact" type="button" class="btn">Contact</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hs227bup/7/

In the above example, which probably isn't exactly how you would want it but it's a starting point, I've added a `<div>` with the class `row` around your group, then added another `div` with the grid classes in.

`col-sm-6` means it will have a width of 50% at the 'small' breakpoint.

`col-lg-4` means it will have a width of 33% (4/12) at the 'large' breakpoint.

`col-xl-3` means it will have a width of 25% (3/12) at the 'extra-large' breakpoint.

By experimenting with these values I imagine you can get it sorted how you want.